# How to Deal with Edge Cases: For Loops and Modulo

Tags: matlab, for-loop, modulo

I'm trying to apply bare-bones image processing to images like this: [image: example image] My for-loop does exactly what I want it to: it allows me to find the pixels of highest intensity, and also remember the coordinates of that pixel. However, the code breaks whenever it encounters a multiple of `rows` – which in this case is equal to 18.

For example, the length of this image (`rows * columns` of `image`) is 414. So there are 414/18 = 23 cases where the program fails (i.e., the number of columns). 
Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish my goal, but this is the only way I could think of sorting an image by pixel intensity while also knowing the coordinates of each pixel. Happy to take suggestions of alternative code, but it'd be great if someone had an idea of how to handle the cases where `mod(x,18) = 0` (i.e., when the index of the vector is divisible by the total # of rows).

```
image = imread('test.tif');      % feed program an image
image_vector = image(:);         % vectorize image

[sortMax,sortIndex] = sort(image_vector, 'descend');   % sort vector so 
                              %that highest intensity pixels are at top
max_sort = [];
[rows,cols] = size(image);

for i=1:length(image_vector)
   x = mod(sortIndex(i,1),rows);         % retrieve original coordinates 
                                         % of pixels from matrix "image"
   y = floor(sortIndex(i,1)/rows) +1;
   if image(x,y) > 0.5 * max            % filter out background noise
      max_sort(i,:) = [x,y];
   else
      continue
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that MATLAB indexing starts at 1, because you do `+1` when you compute `y`. But you forgot to subtract 1 from the index first. Here is the correct computation:

```
index = sortIndex(i,1) - 1;
x = mod(index,rows) + 1;
y = floor(index/rows) + 1;
```

This computation is performed by the function [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html), which I recommend you use.

**Edit**: Actually, `ind2sub` does the equivalent of:

```
x = rem(sortIndex(i,1) - 1, rows) + 1;
y = (sortIndex(i,1) - x) / rows + 1;
```

(you can see this by typing `edit ind2sub`. `rem` and `mod` are the same for positive inputs, so `x` is computed identically. But for computing `y` they avoid the `floor`, I guess it is slightly more efficient.

---

Note also that

```
image(x,y)
```

is the same as

```
image(sortIndex(i,1))
```

That is, you can use the linear index directly to index into the two-dimensional array.

Comment: This answered my question really well, thank you! (my rep is low, so my upvotes aren't public)